# How to safely import JSON object from URL

Tags: javascript

I am making a "webtop" (web desktop) called GopalOS, located here: https://cerebraldatabank.neocities.org/gopalos.html

As you can see in the source, the basic JSON filesystem is structured like this:

```
{
  "folder": {
    type: "dir",
    content: {
      "config": {
        type: "cfg",
        content: "key=val"
      },
      "program": {
        type: "pgm",
        content() {
          alert("Hello World");
          (v => {alert(v);})("Test Text");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, since the `JSON.parse` command doesn't support JS functions, I need a safe way to import a JSON object from a remote URL *without running any code*. The current code uses eval (a case where eval is evil). A remote website may host a malicious file like the following (from [here](https://cerebraldatabank.neocities.org/gopalos-pkg_test-program.txt)):

```
{
  "name": "Test Program",
  "id": "test-program",
  "app-dir": {
    type: "dir",
    content: {
      "oof": {
        type: "pgm",
        content() {
          msgbox(`Hello world! Your OS version is ${getRef("/version")}`);
        },
        ACE: eval(`document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML = "h4xx0r3d"`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how `eval` executes the code in the `ACE` key (it means Arbitrary Code Execution) while parsing the JSON object. I need a safe way to import JSON objects with functions such as the above into a JSON object or variable on the GopalOS page without any code running.

Comment: The structure that you are trying to import is not JSON.  Just because a structure uses object notation, that does not mean that it is JSON.  You are going to have to import it as a script.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I agree with your statements @JonTrauntvein and @RandyCasburn, is there a way to import it as a script but making sure it doesn't run anything when parsed using `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't support functions, from: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259 :

> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a lightweight, **text-based**,
> language-independent data interchange format

JSON is text-based format, maybe you could try to send your function as a string and then use "`eval`" to execute, something like:

```
{ myFunction: "function() { alert('hello world'); } " }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although since this is for a psuedo-package-installation-system, it can be assumed that I don't have control of the content of the remote URL, which may include a malicious script as I described in the question.

Comment: ok let me see if I understand, you are trying to download a javascript file but want to skip the execution of all `eval` statements?

Comment: Yes; I want to skip the execution of *all* statements, in fact (e.g. `eval`, `(()=>{})()`, `(function(){})()`, etc.). These examples may be contained within the JSON object in the `type: "pgm"` parts, but I don't want any code to be executed *while parsing*. EDIT: I want to import a text file just like I demonstrated in my question; i.e. a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: You are downloading those scripts from the browser via ajax or something like that? I think that if you are downloading your script via ajax call you can prevent the execution of the script. I'm not sure but I think that is possible with something like jquery.

Comment: 4 years ago, wow! I'm accepting this answer because it seems to be the only solution to the problem, combined with manual parsing or magic strings like "FUNCTION:" to convert the stringified functions back.